# Register UserManager with Autofac in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-identity, autofac, asp.net-core-mvc

I've just noticed that UserManager changed since MVC5. My question is: how to register UserManager in Autofac in ASP.NET Core ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ASP.NET Core, in many cases the exposed ASP.NET libraries register things with the `IServiceCollection` during `ConfigureServices` at application startup rather than registering with a DI container specifically.

When you call [`services.AddIdentity()`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/c8a276e716064ac40df5a56512e0217b14b48060/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L41), it returns an `IdentityBuilder` on which you can configure additional (or replacement) dependencies.

[`IdentityBuilder.AddUserManager<T>()`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/82863e94447fbe9b1724d3271535c3d2442015d9/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/IdentityBuilder.cs#L172) allows you to specify the replacement user manager type.

When you attach the `IServiceCollection` to Autofac using the `Populate` method ([see our docs](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html)) that's how the `IServiceCollection` registrations get pushed to Autofac.

If you strongly believe you need to register your UserManager directly in Autofac, do it *after* you call `builder.Populate(services)` and register it as an open generic (since the `UserManager<TUser>` expected is also an open generic).

Note the new `UserManager<TUser>` has many more extension points than the old one did, so you may not need to replace *the whole UserManager* - you may be able to swap in just the small piece of override functionality you need.

There is frightfully little documentation on this and it's still changing, so I'd recommend trolling through [the aspnet/Identity repo on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity) where all the source is kept.